# Jquery AJAX timeout not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write a simple Jquery AJAX poll. I want to make sure that requests don't 'back up' in the browser if the web-server is being slow (which in my specific situation is very frequently...).

Here's my code:

```
(function poll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: CONFIG.apiBase,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { name: DESTINATIONS },
        traditional: true,
        success: updateDisplay,
        error: getError,
        complete: setTimeout(poll, 2000),
        timeout: 10000,
    });
})();
```

The way I think this should work is that if the request is successful, it will do `updateDisplay` and then wait 2 seconds before starting another poll request.

However, if my server is being super slow and can't respond within 10 seconds then `getError` will be called, the request will be cancelled and finally it will wait for 2 seconds before trying to poll again.

However, what *actually* happens is that the browser consistently polls the server every 2 seconds, causing the requests to back up if the server is being slow:

[image]

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how `timeout` is supposed to work?

Comment: The problem is your `setTimeout(poll, 2000)` line - that's what's recursively calling your function every 2 seconds.

Comment: You are instantly calling `setTimeout(poll, 2000),`, try wrapping in a function closure.. `function () { setTimeout(poll, 2000); }`

Comment: You are setting the setTimeout id reference to the method...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  He is wanting to retry after 2 seconds after the complete callback, but the setTimeout is been called, not when complete but when he's made the ajax call..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `setTimeout(poll, 2000)` line. At the moment it's calling your `poll()` function every 2 seconds as you don't wait for the previous request to finish. To fix this, wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
(function poll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: CONFIG.apiBase,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { name: DESTINATIONS },
        traditional: true,
        success: updateDisplay,
        error: getError,
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(poll, 2000)
        },
        timeout: 10000,
    });
})();
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked. So, perhaps I am misunderstanding something about Javascript. Does putting `setTimeout`()` directly after `complete:` cause `setTimeout()`to be called at the moment I call `poll()`?

Comment: Yes it does - but that's not exclusive to `setTimeout()`. Your code was executing the `setTimeout()` function immediately and setting its response value to the `complete` property. Returning a reference of a function (as in the above code) means that the logic within the function won't be executed until required. Similar to your `success` and `error` properties - you're providing references of `updateDisplay()` and `getError()` respectively. If you changed it to `success: updateDisplay()` then it would immediately execute the function and set it's response to the value of the property.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense and is obvious now that you've explained it.

Comment: Perfect solution man, thank you for explaining :)